# Reversed battery protection vs reverse discharge protection

Tags: voltage, batteries, current, battery-charging

I'm going through the datasheet of the [MCP73871](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MCP73871-Data-Sheet-20002090E.pdf) battery charge controller.

I want to understand the difference between these two terminologies.

"Reversed-Battery protection" and "Reverse Discharge Protection"

Can someone tell me how and when does each of the scenarios happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Reversed battery* is about an incorrectly connected battery (plus and minus swapped by mistake).

*Reverse discharge* is about the battery discharging through the IC after charging is complete and has stopped, or when the IC is in standby.

Comment: Oh, the IC in the question does not have reversed battery protection right?

Comment: @Newbie: I don't think so, but you would have to check the datasheet to make sure. I did see something about faulty/shorted input protection, but that is a different thing.